# Using pem certificate and key for authentication in powershell https request

Tags: node.js, powershell, https, x509certificate, pem

I have certificates in pem format. 2 files totally, RSA Public and RSA Private keys.
I have to use these to make a https request to the server in powershell script.

I tried adding the certificate using **X509Certificates** Certificate store. But I am not sure how to add the client key certificate( RSA private key ). 
I tried with just the certificate, but I get this error:

```
Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure c
```

hannel.

How can I request with both client certificate and key using powershell?

The powershell script that I have written:

```
$method = "GET"
# Create a dictionary object that allows header storage in Rest call
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("X-Qlik-Xrfkey",$xrfKey)
$headers.Add("X-Qlik-User", "***")


#Get a selection object for all inactive users
$path = "/qrs/app?xrfkey=$xrfKey"
$theCommand = $senseServerHostName + "/qrs" + $path

$ns = "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates"
$store = New-Object "$ns.X509Store"("My","CurrentUser")
#$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My", "CurrentUser")
$store.Open("ReadOnly")
#$certs = $store.Certificates.Find("FindByExtension", $certExtension, $false)
#"$store.Certificates"
    ForEach($cert in $store.Certificates)
    {

        $certToUse = $cert
    }
    "$certToUse"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $theCommand -Headers $headers -Method $method -Certificate $certToUse
```

Although I was able to make the request using the **node.js**
Node code:

```
var https = require('https');    
var fs = require('fs');    
var options = {    
rejectUnauthorized: false,    
hostname: '****',
method: 'GET',
path: '/qrs/app?xrfkey=****',
headers: {
//'Accept': 'application/json',
'x-qlik-xrfkey' : '****',
'X-Qlik-User' : '****'
},
key: fs.readFileSync("C:\\client_key.pem"),
cert: fs.readFileSync("C:\\client.pem")

};
https.get(options, function(res) {
console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
res.on("data", function(chunk) {
console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
});
}).on('error', function(e) {
console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you import the whole PEM into the store? Did certmgr.msc display the certificate as having associated private key? I think you need to convert these files into a PKCS#12 format before being able to import as a certificate with primary key. IIRC Windows does not allow keys to be stored as files when running its SSL engine.

Comment: Yes, you have to merge public certificate and associated private key files to a single PKCS#12 container and then install it to Windows certificate store.

Comment: I have just imported the public key to the certificate store. I will try to merge the public and private into PKCS12 and try to install in the certificate store. And then try to hit the server. Thanks.

Comment: @Vesper : I think there are many certificates in my system. How to know which one to use?

Comment: You should filter by thumbprint I think, the fastest and reliable method. You have there a loop through store, select the one that matches the thumbprint of the cert in your PEM, and then store in your `$certToUse`. Storing thumbprint in the script is kind of accepted, just record that in case of cert renewal you would need to update the script.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of PEM files to PKCS12 worked for me.